# Wouldn't SSD benchmarks ruin the SSD because of repeated iops?

Tags: ssd, benchmarking

I don't know much about SSDs but I have heard that they wear out really quickly are pretty limited in the amount of read/write operations they can handle.

How would SSD benchmarks not ruin an SSD like defragging one would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSD's do not wear out as quickly as you have been led to believe.  Running benchmarks which write to them will decrease their lifespan, but this happens only after thousands to 100's of thousands of writes on that part of the drive.  (See [here](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) for a good test on write lifespan of drives)

I also put to you that defragging - while not good for the drive won't immediately kill it - and because the drive is not a spinning platter any advantage defragging might have would be almost to entirely non-existant - and that is why you don't defrag the drive.  [ Also, defragging commonly moves the same piece of data arround multiple times ]

Comment: Agreed. It generally takes months, if not years, of running benchmarks constantly, 24/7, to wear out an SSD. The biggest reason defragging is no help on SSDs is because of the abstraction layer, with the whole point of defragging being to re-order data on the media, on an SSD Windows has no idea how the media is actually laid out.

Comment: you cant defrag a ssd.  A modern OS will disable the ability to defrag a ssd.  even if you found a defragmentation program that would bypass that restriction, ssd's are designed to spread out the data to prevent wear.  as the defragger wrote the defragged data, the ssd controller would just spread it out across the drive.

Comment: Actually Windows does someimes defrag SSDs - see www.hanselman.com/blog/TheRealAndCompleteStoryDoesWindowsDefragmentYourSSD.aspx for an interesting read.   It appears that there *are* times when defragging an SSD can speed up performance.